# 常に更新があるテーブルの MySQL テーブル文字コードの変更

Tags: mysql

本番運用中のMySQLのデフォルト文字コードが以前と変わってしまってることが発覚して
その間に作られたテーブルの文字コードを修正したいです

ほとんどのテーブルは修正できたのですが

ユニークカラム user_id をもっていて頻繁に更新されるテーブルに

```
ALTER TABLE user_states DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

実行しようとしたところ
`Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry`xxxxxxxx` for key 'index_user_states_on_user_id'
というエラーが出てしまいます

当然ユニーク制約がついてるためレコードは１つしかないです

文字コード変更中に書き込みされて文字列の比較がうまくいかなくて
変なことが起こってるのかなと推測していますが
どうにか更新を行う方法はないでしょうか

要件としては
このテーブル自体は多少（数秒程度なら）欠損がでても問題ないですが
書き込んでる API 側や MySQL 全体を停止したりネットワークから切り離すのはNGです

SQLで明示的にテーブル単位でロックがとれれば

```
LOCK;
ALTER TABLE user_states DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
UNLOCK;
```

みたいな感じで数秒だけ書き込みを抑制して文字コード変更が完了できると思うんですが…
そういうことってできないでしょうか

追記：

Rails のマイグレーションエラー全文

```
execute("ALTER TABLE user_states DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8")
rake stderr: rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'index_user_states_on_user_id': ALTER TABLE user_states DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
は実行するたびに変わっていてそのユーザのデータが直前に更新されているので
文字コード変更とINSERTが重なっておかしなことになってると推測しました
もちろんユニーク制約があるので重複データは存在しません

```
INSERT INTO user_states (user_id, state) VALUES(xxxxxx, xxx)
ON DUPLICATEKEY UPDATE state = state
```

同時に大量に飛んでくる更新クエリはこんな感じです

Comment: [リファレンス](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/alter-table.html)の通り、ALTER TABLE は元のテーブルの一時的なコピーを作成します。MySQL は、そのテーブルを変更しているほかの操作を待ってから、処理を続行します。そのため処理中に処理が挟むことはないはずですが、、一度、更新が発生しないコピー環境で同じエラーが出るかどうか確認してみてください。

Comment: 完全に同じレコード状態で再現というのは無理なんですが、同じスキーマを持ったステージング環境では成功しています。

Comment: index_user_states_on_user_id　のユニーク制約はどのような制約でしょうか？

Comment: `ALTER TABLE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` はテーブルのデフォルトの文字コード＝テーブルにカラムを追加する際のカラムの文字コード の変更なので、既存のカラムの文字コードが変わるわけではないので、これでそのようなエラーになるのは変な気がしますね。

Comment: > ユニーク制約はどのような制約でしょうか？　というのは何を答えればいいんでしょう　MySQL のユニークインデックスでFKでもPKでもないです

Answer (score 0):

MySQL でテーブルをロックするには `LOCK TABLES` を使用します。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/lock-tables.html